# After updating to Ubuntu 23.10 - Two of my HDMI monitors don't turn on

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, radeon, amdgpu

After updating to Ubuntu 23.10 - Two of my HDMI monitors don't turn on I tried they work fine in BIOS.

This is Radeon RX 580

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 9600 x 2880, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-1 connected 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 330mm
   2560x1440     74.94*+
   1920x1440     74.95  
   1600x1200     74.98  
   1440x1080     74.92  
   1400x1050     74.87  
   1280x1024     74.90  
   1280x960      74.86  
   1152x864      74.82  
   1024x768      74.90  
   800x600       74.91  
   640x480       74.77  
   320x240       73.82  
   1920x1200     74.93  
   1680x1050     74.89  
   1440x900      74.98  
   1280x800      74.93  
   1152x720      74.72  
   960x600       74.84  
   928x580       74.58  
   800x500       74.87  
   768x480       74.71  
   720x480       74.51  
   640x400       74.23  
   320x200       73.70  
   2048x1152     74.97  
   1920x1080     74.91  
   1600x900      74.89  
   1368x768      74.90  
   1280x720      74.78  
   1024x576      74.80  
   864x486       74.45  
   720x400       74.23  
   640x350       74.53  
DP-2 connected primary 2560x1440+0+1440 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 330mm
   2560x1440     74.94*+
   1920x1440     74.95  
   1600x1200     74.98  
   1440x1080     74.92  
   1400x1050     74.87  
   1280x1024     74.90  
   1280x960      74.86  
   1152x864      74.82  
   1024x768      74.90  
   800x600       74.91  
   640x480       74.77  
   320x240       73.82  
   1920x1200     74.93  
   1680x1050     74.89  
   1440x900      74.98  
   1280x800      74.93  
   1152x720      74.72  
   960x600       74.84  
   928x580       74.58  
   800x500       74.87  
   768x480       74.71  
   720x480       74.51  
   640x400       74.23  
   320x200       73.70  
   2048x1152     74.97  
   1920x1080     74.91  
   1600x900      74.89  
   1368x768      74.90  
   1280x720      74.78  
   1024x576      74.80  
   864x486       74.45  
   720x400       74.23  
   640x350       74.53  
DVI-D-1 connected 1920x1080+2560+1440 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 530mm x 300mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x720      59.97  
   960x600       59.63  
   928x580       59.88  
   800x500       59.50  
   768x480       59.90  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
HDMI-1 connected 2560x1440+7040+1440 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 330mm
   2560x1440     59.91*+
   1920x1440     59.90  
   1600x1200     59.87  
   1440x1080     59.87  
   1400x1050     59.86  
   1280x1024     59.76  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.78  
   1024x768      59.68  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1680x1050     59.85  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x720      59.75  
   960x600       59.63  
   928x580       59.88  
   800x500       59.50  
   768x480       59.38  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.20  
   320x200       58.96  
   2048x1152     59.90  
   1920x1080     59.88  
   1600x900      59.82  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.45  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
HDMI-2 connected 2560x1440+4480+1440 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 330mm
   2560x1440     59.91*+
   1920x1440     59.90  
   1600x1200     59.87  
   1440x1080     59.87  
   1400x1050     59.86  
   1280x1024     59.76  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.78  
   1024x768      59.68  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1680x1050     59.85  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x720      59.75  
   960x600       59.63  
   928x580       59.88  
   800x500       59.50  
   768x480       59.38  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.20  
   320x200       58.96  
   2048x1152     59.90  
   1920x1080     59.88  
   1600x900      59.82  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.45  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77
```